# Add SSD storage to AWS EC2 reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I am new to AWS EC2 and I have just purchased a t3 medium reserved instance. I would like to add 100 GB of SSD storage to my instance and use it as the instance's primary hard disk. How can I do this? I did not see any option of adding and configuring the SSD disk when I purchased the instance.

I have purchased a linux/unix instance without any AMI. I intend to install Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AWS your SSD disk is known as an [EBS Volume](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/?ebs-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&ebs-whats-new.sort-order=desc).

To update the volume size you would from the EC2 console want to find your current volume and right click on it. Then click modify volume and select your new size.

If you haven't created your instance yet you can specify the size during the wizard.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to clarify that I was a bit confused about how Reserved Instances work. A Reserved Instance is not a physical instance but actually a billing discount which is applied to existing or newly created EC2 instances which match the specification.

Comment: Hi, this is correct. You are simply making a promise to AWS to pay a certain amount each month in return for a certain resource. For that you are given the discount :)